# ActionResult parameter is null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

in my project I have a form with 2 dropdownlist and by clicking a button
it should search in DB and return list of results. this dropdownlist can also be null.
every time I click the button  and sent values to my controller via ajax
it shows this error for all my values:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is my ajax code:

```
    var ValCourse = $("#ddlCourseName").val(); 
    var ValTeacher = $("#ddlTeachers").val();
    var CurrentCourseModel = {
        CourseNameID: ValCourse,
        CourseTeacherID: ValTeacher,
        
    }
    var viewModel = {
        "CurrentCourseModel": CurrentCourseModel
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: UrlFindCourse,
        data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
                alert("Success");
        }
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

and this is my ActionResut:

```
 public ActionResult Courses(CourseModelView viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                CourseRepository repository = new CourseRepository();
                CourseModelView model = new CourseModelView();
             model.CurrentCourseModel.CourseNameID = viewModel.CurrentCourseModel.CourseNameID;
                model.CurrentCourseModel.CourseTeacherID = viewModel.CurrentCourseModel.CourseTeacherID;
               model.CurrentCourseModels = repository.FindCourse(model.CurrentCourseModel);

                return View(model);


            }
            catch (Exception Err)
            {

                LogRepository.Logs.WriteDebug(Err, "error");
                return View("~/ HttpError / 500.html");
            }
        }
```

the ajax receives all the value correctly I tested that.
but action result says all my values are null
please help me
thank you

Comment: If using AJAX, I suggest ApiController instead of Controller. Please have a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you better create a special viewmodel for ajax

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public int CourseNameID {get; set;}
  public int CourseTeacherID {get; set;}
}
```

try this ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: UrlFindCourse,
        data: { viewModel:viewModel},
        success: function (response) {
                alert("Success");
        }
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

and fix the action too

```
 public ActionResult Courses(ViewModel viewModel)
 {
 CourseModelView model = new CourseModelView{ CurrentCourseModel=new CurrentCourseModel()};

model.CurrentCourseModel.CourseNameID = viewModel.CourseNameID;
model.CurrentCourseModel.CourseTeacherID = viewModel.CourseTeacherID;
model.CurrentCourseModels = repository.FindCourse(model.CurrentCourseModel);
```

PS. I had to guess to write this code. Pls post CourseModelView class.